Ping timeouts between VLANs with routing enabled; SSH not working until ping resolves
I am struggling to establish connectivity across two VLANs. Two devices on different VLANs do not talk to each other (SSH, traceroute, etc.) unless I initiate a ping first. Pinging also initially times out and on occasion does not work at all (is inconsistent). The network in question is below:
Network Diagram
I have an HPE 1920S switch with Layer 3 capabilities hosting two VLANs (VLAN 100 and 300). Each VLAN has its own gateway (named ASUS1 and ASUS2, model DSL-AC88U). All devices on VLAN 100 are configured to use ASUS1 (192.168.1.2) as their gateway, and similarly, all devices on VLAN 300 are configured to use ASUS2 (192.168.4.2) as their gateway. Each router hosts a DHCP Server. Both DHCP servers have been added as a DHCP relay on the switch with their respective IPs. Each router has firewall enabled. ASUS1 also serves an OpenVPN Server in TUN configuration which I use (windows1 uses) to connect to the network remotely.
I have enabled routing between the two VLANs on the switch. I have also added the following static routes:

OpenVPN client config file

192.168.1.0/24 via 10.8.0.1
192.168.4.0/24 via 10.8.0.1


ASUS1 Router

10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.1
192.168.4.0/24 via 192.168.1.3


Switch

10.8.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.2 (Next Hop Interface: VLAN 100)
192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.3 (Next Hop Interface: VLAN 100)
192.168.4.0/24 via 192.168.4.3 (Next Hop Interface: VLAN 300)


ASUS2 Router

10.8.0.0/24 via 192.168.4.3
192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.4.3



I have confirmed the following:

The switch has the correct entries for the source and destination devices in its ARP table
The ARP tables on destination and source devices, the two routers and the switch DO NOT change BEFORE or AFTER the pings resolve
The issue persists with the firewalls on routers disabled
There are no firewalls on linux1 or linux2
I can ping all source and destination devices (except for 10.8.0.2 - the VPN client) from the switch and they start working immediately
There are no IP conflicts

For diagnosis, I am including various dumps that show my traceroute, ping and SSH attempts between devices. I am also including them in order, because I believe it matters, since the behavior of traceroute and ping changes from one attempt to another.
The first dump shows my traceroute attempts from my VPN client (windows1) on 10.8.0.2 to 192.168.1.19, 192.168.4.20 and 192.168.4.21, respectively. Note the first asterisk on the last hop when crossing VLANs.
(base) PS C:\Users\myuser> tracert -d 192.168.1.19
 
Tracing route to 192.168.1.19 over a maximum of 30 hops
 
  1   141 ms   141 ms   143 ms  10.8.0.1
  2   143 ms   142 ms   142 ms  192.168.1.19
 
Trace complete.
 
(base) PS C:\Users\myuser> tracert -d 192.168.4.20
 
Tracing route to 192.168.4.20 over a maximum of 30 hops
 
  1   142 ms   142 ms   142 ms  10.8.0.1
  2   143 ms   143 ms   143 ms  192.168.1.3
  3     *      142 ms   142 ms  192.168.4.20
 
Trace complete.
 
(base) PS C:\Users\myuser> tracert -d 192.168.4.21
 
Tracing route to 192.168.4.21 over a maximum of 30 hops
 
  1   142 ms   142 ms   142 ms  10.8.0.1
  2   143 ms   143 ms   145 ms  192.168.1.3
  3     *      141 ms   141 ms  192.168.4.21
 
Trace complete.

The second dump shows my traceroute and ping attempts from 192.168.4.20 to 192.168.1.19. The first traceroute finishes with a '!H' and two asterisks. The second traceroute fails to resolve and I send a Keyboard Interrupt. The ping works but with 33% packet loss. The final traceroute attempt is successful after the ping.
myuser@192.168.4.20:~$ sudo traceroute -d 192.168.1.19
[sudo] password for myuser:
traceroute to 192.168.1.19 (192.168.1.19), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.4.2)  0.464 ms  0.515 ms  0.649 ms
 2  192.168.4.3 (192.168.4.3)  3.674 ms  5.102 ms  11.126 ms
 3  192.168.4.3 (192.168.4.3)  14.924 ms !H * *
 
myuser@192.168.4.20:~$ sudo traceroute -d 192.168.1.19
traceroute to 192.168.1.19 (192.168.1.19), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.4.2)  0.488 ms  0.504 ms  0.640 ms
 2  192.168.4.3 (192.168.4.3)  2.594 ms  3.597 ms  4.354 ms^C
 
myuser@192.168.4.20:~$ ping 192.168.1.19
PING 192.168.1.19 (192.168.1.19) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.19: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.410 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.19: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.462 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.19 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 2 received, 33.3333% packet loss, time 2080ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.410/0.436/0.462/0.026 ms
 
myuser@192.168.4.20:~$ sudo traceroute -d 192.168.1.19
traceroute to 192.168.1.19 (192.168.1.19), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.4.3 (192.168.4.3)  1.671 ms  2.486 ms  3.258 ms
 2  192.168.1.19 (192.168.1.19)  0.477 ms  0.464 ms  0.451 ms

The third dump shows how the SSH connection from 192.168.4.21 to 192.168.19 initially times out, but eventually starts working after a ping. Note the 'Redirect Host (New nexthop: 192.168.4.3)' warning before the ping starts working.
(base) myuser@192.168.4.21:~$ ssh myuser@192.168.1.19 -p [redacted]
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.19 port [redacted]: Connection timed out
 
(base) myuser@192.168.4.21:~$ sudo traceroute -d 192.168.1.19
[sudo] password for myuser:
traceroute to 192.168.1.19 (192.168.1.19), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.4.2)  0.373 ms  30.085 ms  30.066 ms
 2  192.168.4.3 (192.168.4.3)  2.299 ms  3.130 ms  3.890 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * *^C
 
(base) myuser@192.168.4.21:~$ ping 192.168.1.19
PING 192.168.1.19 (192.168.1.19) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.4.2: icmp_seq=2 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.4.3)
64 bytes from 192.168.1.19: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.632 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.19: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.483 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.19: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=0.389 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.19: icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=0.395 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.19 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 4 received, 20% packet loss, time 4132ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.389/0.474/0.632/0.098 ms
 
(base) myuser@192.168.4.21:~$ sudo traceroute -d 192.168.1.19
traceroute to 192.168.1.19 (192.168.1.19), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.4.3 (192.168.4.3)  1.483 ms  2.294 ms  3.037 ms
 2  192.168.1.19 (192.168.1.19)  0.439 ms  0.405 ms  0.385 ms
 
(base) myuser@192.168.4.21:~$ ssh myuser@192.168.1.19 -p [redacted]
The authenticity of host '[192.168.1.19]:[redacted] ([192.168.1.19]:[redacted])' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:[redacted].
This key is not known by any other names.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? ^C

The final dump shows how the SSH and traceroute attempts both fail between 10.8.0.2 and 192.168.4.21. The traceroute between the two had worked as seen in the first dump, but something clearly has changed between attempts...
(base) PS C:\Users\myuser> ssh myuser@192.168.4.21
ssh: connect to host 192.168.4.21 port 22: Connection timed out
 
(base) PS C:\Users\myuser> tracert -d 192.168.4.21
 
Tracing route to 192.168.4.21 over a maximum of 30 hops
 
  1   142 ms   142 ms   142 ms  10.8.0.1
  2   143 ms   143 ms   143 ms  192.168.1.3
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5

My question: how can I get SSH and traceroute to work consistently over VPN and between two devices onsite but on different VLANs, without having to ping first, as if they were on the same subnet?

That "host redirect" is probably the giveaway.
Give your hosts (linux1 & 2, etc) static routes to the other subnets so that they don't always start by sending to their default gateway just to get a host redirect.

Thank you! Adding static routes to each host did the trick. I no longer get the "host redirect" warnings, and I can now initiate an SSH connection to linux1 & 2 from windows1 without having to ping either one first. I believe this will also save the unnecessary round trip from the switch to the default gateway on VLAN 300 when communicating with other hosts on VLAN 100.
